# Swift: how to wait for sound to be played?

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder, completionhandler

Hey I have programmed a recorder app just like voice memos from apple. I also have the same sounds for starting and stopping the recording. The problem is that the sound at the start is on the recording. Is there a way to wait for the sound to be finished playing and only then start the recording?

Right now I have this:

```
@State var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
@State var isRecording = false // boolean, true -> recorder is recording


let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let fileName = url.appendingPathComponent("myRcd.m4a") // set the location for the Audiofile
let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
] // settings for the recording

self.recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileName, settings: settings)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1113) // play the soundeffect
self.recorder.record() // start recording
self.isRecording.toggle() // change isRecording to true
```

Comment: Look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound). -> *To know when a sound has finished playing, call the AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(_:_:_:_:_:) function to register a callback function.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, this is how I solved it:

```
@State var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
@State var isRecording = false // boolean, true -> recorder is recording


let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let fileName = url.appendingPathComponent("myRcd.m4a") // set the location for the Audiofile
let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
] // settings for the recording


// ---------------------------------------------------- the part I changed
self.isRecording.toggle() // change isRecording to true
self.recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileName, settings: settings)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(1113) { // play the sound and wait until it is finished
    self.recorder.record() // start recording when sound is played
}
```

Thanks to [@burnsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6950415/burnsi)

Comment: Thanks for following up by adding a complete answer. (Voted.) That makes your question really useful for somebody in the future who has the same question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I read the help center and don't really get what's wrong with my answer. Maybe you could clarify what you mean? Thanks.